# How to Access a File via Android Context

Tags: android, file

I am trying to access a file from the context, but I am unable to do this. I use context.openFileInput() method but it returns a stream while I need a File object of the file that i want to access.

Yours,

Comment: Why do you want file object for ? Is it to check whether particular file exists or not ? otherwise FileInputStream can be used for most of   the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below function of context which will return File

```
public File getFileStreamPath (String name)
```

**Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a file created with openFileOutput(String, int) is stored.**

Answer (score 0):

try using this  `context.getFileStreamPath(String name)`

for more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Answer (score 0):

show one or two line of code -- since you profile shows engineer what Java does is about everything is an "Object" but you can get typing information with getClass().getName()

to get a File object on Android you use abstract File getDir(String name, int mode) in context but when you say stream it sounds like you are getting something of the general nature of a file ...

Answer (score 0):

`context.getFileStreamPath(fileName);` will help you. "fileName" should be String type.